# Error due to an unexpected character, how do I fix?

Tags: r

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
ch4_useful_data <- ch4_data %>%
  select("CH4 (ppm)", "Latitude", "Longitude")
```

followed by:

```
Map <- get_map(location=c(lon = -79.15784454, lat = 40.61871338), source="google", maptype="satellite", zoom=16)
Map_Plot <- ggmap(Map, extent = "panel", ylab = "Latitude", xlab = "Longitude")
Map_Plot + geom_point(data = chr_data, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = "CH4 (ppm)"), size = 8, alpha = 0.5) scale_color_gradient(colours = myPalette(100), limits = c(2, 15), name = "[CH4] ppm") +
  labs( y = "Latitude", x = "Longitude", title = "Methane Map")
```

This latter chunk returns:

> "Error: unexpected symbol in "Map_Plot + geom_point(data = chr_data, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = "CH4 (ppm)"), size = 8, alpha = 0.5) scale_color_gradient"

I've been staring at it for an hour, what character is unexpected here? Or is it a deeper issue related to something like data formatting from a previous step?

Comment: There is a lot of help available on SO, but you have to provide a bit more information for the best possible answers. Read about how to ask questions for R on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

There was a `+` missing before `scale_color_gradient`.  Also, specify the column name in backquotes where there are spaces in the name

```
Map_Plot  +
     geom_point(data = chr_data, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = `CH4 (ppm)`), size = 8, alpha = 0.5) + 
     scale_color_gradient(colours = myPalette(100), limits = c(2, 15), name = "[CH4] ppm") +
  labs( y = "Latitude", x = "Longitude", title = "Methane Map")
```